# Using a loop to select multiple images, process and then output to a directory

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

at the moment, the below code extracts faces from a single image and then outputs those faces to a folder. How can I input a directory full of images and do the same thing? I can't seem to add a directory into the image - face_recognition.load_image_file(C:/directory) as it keeps coming back with permission denied error. Is there a way I can ask it to loop through all the images in a particular directory and then output them to my path?

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition

image = face_recognition.load_image_file(r"C:\Users\Julio\Desktop\Face Extraction\Input\IMG_0421.JPG")
path = r"C:\Users\Julio\Desktop\Face Extraction\Output\face"

face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))

face_counter = 0
for face_location in face_locations:
    top, right, bottom, left = face_location
    print("I found a face in image location Top: {}, Left: {}, Bottom: {}, Right: {}".format(top, left, bottom, right))

    face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
    pil_image.save(str(path) + str(face_counter) + ".jpg")
    face_counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently which I hope will be of help to you.  I basically set my path to a variable, then the listdir of that path to a variable called img_list, then cycled through that:

```
# media thumbnails
path = "/media/default_thumbnails/"
img_list = listdir(path)

for image in img_list:
    """
    Need to open an image file from the directory as a PIL Image. 
    Then create a BytesIO and save that as the thumbnail.
    """
    try:
        img = PILImage.open(path + image)
        rawfile = BytesIO()
        img.save(rawfile, format='jpeg')
        mt = MediaThumbnail.objects.create()
    mt.thumbnail.save(image, rawfile)
    rawfile.close()
except:
    print(f"   skipping {image}")
print("   thumbnails created")
```

To integrate that into your code you'd do something like:

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition

path = "C:\Users\Julio\Desktop\Face Extraction\Input"
img_list = listdir(path)

for input_img in img_list:

    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(input_img)
    [.... the rest of your code ]
```

Comment: sorry I'm a bit of a noob to python - what does that look like integrated into my code?

Comment: so the initial error I got from that is listdir is not defined.

Comment: would it be, img_list = os.listdir(path)

Comment: You need to import listdir like this:  `from os import listdir `